# Custom menu link does not show up under "List links" but is in the database

Tags: routes

I have three menus with six links each using the i18n module.

All of these links are to panel pages.  On one menu, however, there is an additional link to another custom panel that does not appear in the Menu UI (under *List Links*)  but is present in the database (I found it in the menu_links table).

When I go to the panel of the ghost link, the option for showing a menu link is disabled.

How can I put this link back in the UI?  Or should I simply delete it from the database and re-create it in the UI?

**EDIT**: I tried adding the link in the menu manually, but then it shows up twice.

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to the menu and add that link in the menu and it would start showing up.

Comment: When I did that, the link started appearing twice.  It's already in the database, just not showing up in the UI...

Comment: Remove the link from the database then and you would see the link only once..

Comment: depending on what else is relying on that db entry, it could cause a lot of damage to simply delete it. I would think first any reference to the menu entry would need to be changed over to the new entry (while showing duplicate) before the actual db entry is removed